# Using !n in script or interactive mode

Tags: bash, command-history, bashrc, bash-script

I add to `~/.bashrc` the following code:

```
test_exclamation () {
  printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xargs echo
}
bind -x '"\eX": test_exclamation'
```

I write to bash prompt buffer

```
$ !1700
```

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then command with number 1700 from history performs. If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, I got an output:

```
!1700
```

How to change `test_exclamation` function to print command under number 1700?

Comment: How is `$READLINE_LINE` defined?

Comment: @Ketan - This is an built in BASH variable. Have a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-READLINE_005fLINE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
test_exclamation () {   READLINE_LINE=$( history -p "$READLINE_LINE" ) ;  }
```